SwiftUI DatePicker time from now until tomorrow same time
I'm looking to add a simple DatePicker time selector in my SwiftUI app. The idea is to select the time of your next appointment and calculate when you need to leave.
In the DatePicker you can select the date ranges by using the in: startDate...endDate functionality so it would make sense to set the date range to be:
    let startDate = Date()
    let endDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 24 * 3600.0)


but from what I can see, the time picker only allows me to select the time from now until midnight tomorrow. What am I doing wrong here?

DatePicker("What time do you have to arrive at?", selection: $appointmentTimes.arrivalTime,
                           in: startDate...endDate,
                           displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                    .onAppear {
                        UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 5
                    }

Update:
Removing the display components gives me an ability to show the date which would then work somewhat correctly, allowing me to select tomorrow times until now. But since I want to keep it simple, I would rather have just have it show the times.


So I've decided to recreate the time picker with a custom view instead. I was hoping to avoid it, but it was actually an interesting use case because dealing with dates and times and timezones is not as simple as you might think. Good that I'm making a TIME grasping app .
So the answer to this was to create a CustomTimePicker based picker, based on two separate Hour and Minute SwiftUI Picker Views. When analysing the alarm clock app in iOS it seems as if this is how it was done in there too, as this was my initial inspiration.
There were a couple of things to handle which was the initial problem, how do you set the time so that it's not set in the past? As a Time picker is a DateTime picker,  I had to check if the desired date together with the time is bigger than now. If it's not, then you're probably talking about tomorrow, or at least this is what I'm going to assume when calculating your appointment time.
Then there's the - "set time to now", which technically is optional but it's a nice touch when you load and it shows you the current time.
Here's the full code that you can try it out yourself.
//
//  CustomTimePicker.swift
//  ADHD Time
//
//  Created by Piotr Poliwoda on 28/07/2024.
//
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTimePicker: View {
    @State var selectedTime = Date.now

    @State var hours = Int(Date.now.formatted(Date.FormatStyle().hour())) ?? 0
    @State var minutes = Int(Date.now.formatted(Date.FormatStyle().minute())) ?? 0

    init() {
        reinitialiseSelectedTimeOnAppear()
    }
    
    func reinitialiseSelectedTimeOnAppear() {
        let anHourAhead = (Int(Date.now.formatted(Date.FormatStyle().hour())) ?? 0) + 1
        hours = anHourAhead == 24 ? 0 : anHourAhead
        minutes = Int(Date.now.formatted(Date.FormatStyle().minute())) ?? 0
    }
    
    func setSelectedTime() {
        let today = Date.now
        
        let dateFormatterFromNowToString = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterFromNowToString.dateFormat = "dd/MM/y"

        let formatterFromStringToDate = DateFormatter()
        formatterFromStringToDate.dateFormat = "dd/MM/y HH:mm"

        let todaysDate = dateFormatterFromNowToString.string(from: today)
        
        let paddedHours = String(format: "%02d", hours)
        let paddedMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let selectedStringAllTogether = "\(todaysDate) \(paddedHours):\(paddedMinutes)"
        
        let recomposedDate = formatterFromStringToDate.date(from: selectedStringAllTogether) ?? Date.now
        
        if (recomposedDate > Date.now) {
            selectedTime = recomposedDate
        } else {
            selectedTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: recomposedDate)!
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Select your time")
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Picker("Hours", selection: $hours) {
                ForEach(0..<24) { hour in
                    let pad = hour < 10 ? "0" : ""
                    Text("\(pad)\(hour)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: -14))
            .frame(width: 110)
            .onChange(of: hours) {
                setSelectedTime()
            }
            Picker("Minutes", selection: $minutes) {
                ForEach(0..<12) { minuteSet in
                    let minutes = minuteSet * 5
                    let pad = minutes < 10 ? "0" : ""
                    Text("\(pad)\(minutes)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .tag(minutes)
                        
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: -14, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .frame(width: 110)
            .onChange(of: minutes) {
                setSelectedTime()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            reinitialiseSelectedTimeOnAppear()
            setSelectedTime()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    CustomTimePicker()
}

Now it looks like this:

